# My old user account is deleted but I still can see my old comments. I want to delete them as well

Tags: support, comments, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I still see my comments that I posted from my deleted user account. How can I delete them?

Comment: perhaps flag one for moderator attention and ask for them all to be deleted... but the mods may not delete